# Kotlin programming basics

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to learn Kotlin and I come with a question while using functions.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(max(20, 10))
}

fun max(a: Int, b: Int) = if (a > b) a else b
```

Here I have a function MAX. Now is there any difference between above implementation and below implementation of function MAX though both gives same output.

```
fun max(a: Int, b: Int): Int?{
    if(a > b)
        return a
    else
        return b
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three main differences between the two functions:

1. The return type is different (as voddan has pointed out).
2. The body style is different (this is just syntactical sugar).
3. The first function's bytecode is more efficient.

---

## The return type

Kotlin has [nullable types and non-null types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types). [`Int`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/) can be used in Kotlin code as nullable, `Int?`, or non-null, `Int`, and on the JVM are mapped to [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and [`int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) respectively.

## The body style

[Single-expression functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions) in Kotlin can be declared more concisely using an expression body (as opposed to the normal block body). The following generate the same bytecode:

### Expression body style

```
fun max(a: Int, b: Int) = if (a > b) a else b
```

The return type can also be declared explicitly:

```
fun max(a: Int, b: Int): Int = if (a > b) a else b
```

### Block body style

```
fun max(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return if (a > b) a else b
}
```

## The bytecode

The first function's bytecode loads the value based on the condition and then returns the loaded value while the second function's bytecode declares two blocks each defining it's own load and return resulting in more generated bytecode.

```
   L0
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    ILOAD 0
    ILOAD 1
    IF_ICMPLE L1
    ILOAD 0
    GOTO L2
   L1
    ILOAD 1
   L2
    IRETURN
```

vs.

```
   L0
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    ILOAD 0
    ILOAD 1
    IF_ICMPLE L1
   L2
    LINENUMBER 9 L2
    ILOAD 0
    IRETURN
   L3
   L1
    LINENUMBER 11 L1
    ILOAD 1
    IRETURN
```

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is the return type: it is `Int` in the first case, and `Int?` in the second case.

That difference affects you in 2 ways:

1) The code that uses `max` in the 2nd case cannot know if it returns `null` or not, so it must check for it every time (with `if-else` or other techniques)

2) Underlying byte code for the 1st case (assuming you use JVM backend) uses primitive `int`, not boxed `Integer`. This can give you a significant performance boost.

Comment: so what is difference between returning "Int" and "Int?" and why is there "=" sign in function in first case

Comment: "Int?" is nullable and "Int" is not

Comment: @John as syntax of function should be like this "fun fun_name() { }" but in first case it is like "fun fun_name() ="

Comment: When you use `fun fun_name() = <expression>`, the compiler will automatically infer the return type of the function to be the type of the expression. With brackets, the default return type is `Unit`, so you have to specify the type if you return something else.

Comment: @deadpool007 please read the [official documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html) - it is quite concise and clear about all the syntax nuances